# Modeling trimmed mean

Tags: regression, trimmed-mean

In OLS, the conditional mean $E(Y \mid X)$ is modeled as a function of some regressors $X$, i.e.
$$
  E(Y \mid X) = X \beta.
$$

Is there a regression technique that allows to model the conditional trimmed mean of $Y$?

(Least absolute deviations will lead to the extreme case of maximal trimming.)

Is there a direct relation between this question and [least trimmed squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_trimmed_squares) estimator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The LTS (the wiki page you point to) is the regression equivalent of the trimmed mean: in LTS, one minimizes the sum of the smallest $h$ residuals to  $\pmb x'\pmb\beta$, the regression hyper-plane, instead of the sum of the $h$ smallest residual to a fixed number $\mu$.

However, as pointed out at the end of the wiki article, exact computation of the LTS is impossible except for small data sets. This is why [0] introduced FastLTS, a fast algorithm to compute a consistent estimator of the exact LTS for moderately sized data set. You can find good implementations of FastLTS is many software packages.  R has one (function [robustbase::ltsReg](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/robustbase/index.html)).

- [0] Rousseeuw, P. Van Driessen, K. (2006). Computing LTS Regression for Large Data Sets. Data Mining and Knowledge Discovery. vol:12 issue:1 pages:29-45.

Answer (score 1):

Look up [robust statistics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robust_statistics) and M-estimators.  Essentially, rather than assuming that $P(Y|X) \sim N[y-\beta X, \sigma^2]$, you choose some other function which downweights outliers.  It's not quite a trimmed mean as such, but you get all the benefits likelihood methods, including standard errors on coefficients.

Tukey's biweight is a commonly used function.